# Append 2 columns from a single table into one column in SAS

Tags: sas, analysis, proc-sql

Can someone please help me with this sort of append. Here is the input data -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNVNl.png)

Here is the output I'm expecting -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCHjA.png)

Attached is the code for input data -

```
data have;
input ID Emp1 $ Emp2 $;
cards;
1 Ani Mia
1 Pat Vul
1 Kiu Max
run;
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE WORK.Append_Table AS 
SELECT Emp1 AS All_Emp FROM WORK.HAVE  /* Table 1, Column 1 */
 OUTER UNION CORR 
SELECT Emp2 AS All_Emp FROM WORK.HAVE  /* Table 1, Column 2 */
;
Quit;
```

Comment: I only have one table that has 2 columns which I need to append. This solution is not working. @Niqua

Comment: Sorry, misread your query. I've edited the code, try again

Answer (score 1):

The SET statement can stack data.

```
data want;
  set 
    have(keep=emp1 rename=emp1=all_emp)
    have(keep=emp2 rename=emp2=all_emp)
  ;
run;
```